# Given a continuous function $f : I → R$, show that if $f$ is diﬀerentiable at $c$ and $c$ is a local extremum, then $f'(c) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Let $f : I → R$ be a continuous function on a open interval which has a local extremum at some $c\in I$. If $f$ is diﬀerentiable at $c$ then $f'(c) = 0$.

Is the following proof valid?

We study the diﬀerence quotient of $f$ at $x_0$:

$$\frac {f(x)−f(c)}{x−c}$$

Since $f$ is diﬀerentiable, we know that its limit exists for $x → c$.

Since $f$ is continuous and has a local extremum at $c$ by assumption, we get:

$$f(x)−f(c) = 0 \;(\forall x \in I)$$

Thus, by the quotient rule for limits, we ﬁnd:

$$f '(c) = \lim_{ x\to c} \,\frac {f(x)−f(c)}{x−c}
= \lim_{ x \to c} (0) = 0$$

Comment: Why $f(x)-f(c)=0$ for every $x\in I$? If you want other proof look at right limit and left limit.

Comment: This was the only bit I wasn't certain about. I didn't know if I had to include the right and left limit if the function is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong: If $f$ has a local maximum at $c$, then
$$f(x)\le f(c)$$
for $x$ near $c$.
What means this for the sign of
$$\frac{f(x)−f(c)}{x−c}$$
for $x$ near $c$ in the cases $x>c$, $x<c$?

Answer (score 0):

Just because $f$ is continuous and has a local extremum at $c$, does not imply that
$$ f(x) - f(x) = 0\;\forall x \in I\,.$$
The latter would imply that $f(x) = f(c)$ for all $x \in I$, meaning that $f$ would be the constant function.

Assume $c$ is a local maximum. Then use the definition of a local maximum to show that
$$ \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} \leq 0\,,$$
for $x \geq c$ and then pass to the limit. Similarly you can show the other inquality thus concluding that $f'(c)=0$.